# (ASP.Net) google oauth2 returning token after hash instead of in a querystring

Tags: asp.net, oauth, google-api

I have a project that requires an ASP.Net app to use google credentials and so authorization is in oauth 2.0.

I have formed a valid request for authorization to google's APIs, but the response (and the token with it) is returned after a hash character '#'.  Kinda like:

[sample http link:]  myredirecturi.com/oauthcallback#token=thetokenvalue...

What I was expecting was it was in the format of a querystring, i.e., after a question mark '?':

[sample http link:] myredirecturi.com/oauthcallback?token=thetokenvalue...

The reason I am having problems with this is I can't reference the token in server-side ASP.net.

To call this request, basically what I am doing is doing a Response.redirect to google's url, but it seems to think I need a client-side response to it.

So, my question is, how do I make google respond in a querystring?

If it helps, this is what I'm basing most of my work on: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your auth request URL, are you setting `response_type=token`? That would cause the server to return an access token in the fragment. This is the Client-side flow described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

If you're performing OAuth in a web server (and it sounds like you are), you should use the Web server flow described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer -- you specify `response_type=code` which will result in an authorization code that you can exchange for a refresh token and access token in a subsequent request.

Comment: Yes, I am using response_type=token.  And I'm following the link you sent for the WebServer flow.  Like I've said, I'm getting there using a Response.Redirect(google's url).  But for some reason, the response has the token after a hash, instead of in a querystring format

Comment: The Web Server link mentions `response_type=code`, not `token`. When using the Client-side (aka Implicit Grant) flow, it's conformant with the spec to specify the token in the fragment, not in the query string: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-26#section-4.2 -- if you're making OAuth requests and need to get the token in your server, you should use the Web Server flow.

Comment: oh wow, I totally missed that one, I copied it from the Client side flow.  So, I changed it to response_type=code and now it is replying with a querystring.  Thank you sir.